# Stop animation for expandAll on a tree panel

Tags: animation, extjs, tree, extjs4, extjs4.1

IE8 has a horrible time collapsing a medium sized tree panel with multiple columns. It is way too slow.

I am looking for ways to speedup the transitions from expandAll to collapseAll states.
One such way would seem to me is cancelling animation for IE8. It seems that in previous versions there were options that maybe specified on expand/collpase methods to enable or disable animation. However I don't see these options anymore.

Has anyone done this on 4.1x?

Comment: yes it is horrible (on ie8). i moved to multi-level grouping instead which performs much better for larger datasets. see here for[link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226739-MultiGrouping-and-MultiGroupingSummary&p=898917#post898917)... i am trying out slickgrid and it looks awesome see this [link](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html). I reused my server side extjs4 tree model for slickgrid ( do a dfs and associate the correct parent ids). HTH

Comment: appreciate the comment. The Slick grid looks .. well slick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreePanel has animate property that can be set to disable the animation:

> animate:!Ext.isIE

Tried this and it works. However the effect is opposite to what I expected :(
With no animation IE just sits there and thinks it over, and over and over until it calculates every node and then repaints the entire tree at once. This makes it look like it takes longer not shorter, since with animation you can at least see IE struggling ...